# PInvoke FatalExecutionEngineError

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I use PInvoke to access a C++ library from c# code. But I have problems using the following function:

```
UINT32 myfunc(IN char * var1, IN UINT32 var2, INOUT UINT16 * var3, OUT UINT8 * var4)
```

documentation says:

> return parameter is error code
>
> var1 is a string
>
> var2 is an integer
>
> var3 is a pointer to an integer (the value will be the size of var4, the value will be changed by the function)
>
> var4 is a pointer to a buffer that will be filled by the function

When I use

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int myfunc(string var1, int var2, out int var3, 
    out byte[] var4);
```

The function gives the following exception:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users...\Documents\Projects...\bin\Debug...vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x74292e44, on thread 0x2edc. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I tried to work with parameters to see if I can get anything and I changed charset as below:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int myfunc(string var1, int var2, out int var3, out byte[] var4);
```

In this case, it does not give FatalExecutionEngineError, instead the function returns without error. But the return value indicates that an internal error hass occurred in the function. (I don't know why the charset change prevents the FatalExecutionEngineError.)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that `var2` is an integer? From your function prototype it seems that `var2` is a **pointer** to an integer (`IN UINT32 * var2`).

Comment: Moreover, you may want to clarify more things for your native function. For example: what is the encoding used by the "string" in `var1`? Is this UTF-8? Is this just a pure ASCII string? And what are the units of the size value stored in `var3`? Is this a size in bytes, or in something else? Moreover, MSDN has some examples on marshaling arrays [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719546(v=vs.71).aspx): it seems that `[In, Out] byte[] var4` could be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The p/invoke declaration should look like this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int myfunc(
    string var1, 
    uint var2, 
    ref ushort var3, 
    byte[] var4
);
```

And then you call it like this:

```
string var1 = "...";
uint var2 = ...;
ushort var3 = 1024;//use whatever length buffer you want to pass
byte[] var4 = new byte[var3];
int retval = myfunc(var1, var2, ref var3, var4);
Array.Resize(ref var4, var3);
```

The way that the native code works is that it expects the calling code to allocate the buffer, `var4`. The calling code says how long the buffer is in `var3`.

Then when the native code returns, `var3` contains the actual length of the buffer. Or perhaps the number of bytes that were copied. The former is more useful. Assuming the former then you could perhaps write it like this:

```
string var1 = "...";
uint var2 = ...;
ushort var3 = 0;
int retval = myfunc(var1, var2, ref var3, null);
byte[] var4 = new byte[var3];
int retval = myfunc(var1, var2, ref var3, var4);
```

You should be checking return values etc.

I can't be 100% sure exactly how to call the function because there's no enough information in your question. At least the p/invoke signature now matches your C++ code.

Comment: your solution works! thank you. And you are right var2 is integer actually, I accidentally put an asterisk there. I edited it so the the actual answer will be without ref parameters before var2. also the below works (Tell me if there is problem in using "out" instead of "ref" parameters):
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int myfunc(string var1, int var2, out int var3, byte[] var4);

Comment: In the C++ code, `var3` is clearly marked as `INOUT` which matches up to `ref`. In other words you are passing a value in as well as reading it back out. Also do not the types that I use. `var2` is unsigned, and `var3` is 16 bytes wide.

Comment: I know this is an old solution but it just saved me hours of troubleshooting (same issue, need to pass a byte array that gets written to by the c++ code).

My question is why do you NOT need to add the ref and why does that actually cause the error? Given that the c++ function is writing to the byte array it seems off you don't need to specify it is being passed by ref as I would think by default the parameter would be read only?

Comment: @Nathan Because the rules are that arrays are marshaled as pointer to their first element. Regarding the data flowing from callee back to caller you make a good point. An implementation detail means that because `byte[]` is blittable then the managed array can be pinned. Which means that, for such blittable types, the data in fact flows in both directions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for that response, much appreciated as I hate just doing something without understanding why and again this issue caused me so many hours of pain. I guess using ref I ended up sending a pointer of a pointer? and given the error message I just kept ignoring the byte array as being the problem parameter.

Anyway, again thanks!

Comment: @nathan Yeah, ref array is double pointer

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially a very dangerous function, it can arbitrarily spray junk into memory through the 4th argument.  If it is well designed (fingers crossed) then it should allow you to measure the required buffer size first.  Arbitrary guess:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int myfunc(string name, ref int var2, ref int buflen, IntPtr buf);

string name = "foo";
int var2 = 42; //???
int len = 0;
int error = myfunc(name, ref var2, ref len, IntPtr.Zero);
if (error == BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) {
    IntPtr buf = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(len);
    try {
       error = myfunc(name, ref var2, ref len, buf);
       if (error == OK) {
           var bytes = new bytes[len];
           Marshal.Copy(buf, bytes, 0, len);
           //...
       }
    }
    finally {
       Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buf);
    }
}
if (error != OK) handleError(error);
```

This was pretty heavy guessing.  If the function does not in fact allow you to ask for the required buffer size first then you should change the C code so it works like this.  Only way to safely call it.

Comment: This. ALWAYS (if you can) pass in the size/length of the buffer, lest you leave yourself open to a host of not only Marshalling difficulties, but other fun things like buffer overflows, etc. If you can't predetermine the size of the buffer, allow for passing of NULL to the native call which will then "return" you back the size required (Win32 functions commonly take this approach).